# magento 2: While magento data migrate from magento 1 to 2 , is there customer password working?

Tags: magento-2.1

While migrating data from **Magento 1 to Magento 2**, do we lose customer password? I mean, Is customer password working when we migrate Magento 1 to Magento 2 using data migrate tools or need to reset that?

Comment: this one might help you https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/223588/customer-password-not-working-after-migration-from-magento-1-to-magento-2/223591#223591

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Customer password not working after migration from Magento 1 to Magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/223588/customer-password-not-working-after-migration-from-magento-1-to-magento-2)